# Reducing queries overhead when fetching related fields

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a simple blog app with tags.

```
class AbstractDate(models.Model):
     created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

     class Meta:
        abstract = True

class AbstractTitleData(AbstractDate):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Post(AbstractTitleData):
     body = models.TextField()
     views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
     likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
     picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created"]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Tag(models.Model):
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=15)
   post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="tags") 

   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.slug
```

For example, in my db have two posts. There are post A and post B with tags 'a', 'b', 'c', and 'd', 'e', 'f' respectively. To reduce queries to the database, I'm trying to use [extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) method.

```
condition = 'blog_post.id = blog_tag.post_id'
p = Post.objects.all().extra(select={'t':'blog_tag.slug'},tables=["blog_tag"],where=[condition])
```

Result:

```
[<Post: A>, <Post: A>, <Post: A>, <Post: B>, <Post: B>, <Post: B>]
for post in p: print post.t
'a'
'b'
'c'
'd'
'e'
'f'
```

How can I get a copy of each post with all their tags listed in one attr, like so:

```
p =[<Post: A>, <Post: B>]
for post in p: print post.t
['a','b','c']
['d','e','f']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't use `extra` for that at all. Instead, use `prefetch_related` to fetch the posts and all their associated tags in two queries:

```
p = Post.objects.all().prefetch_related('tag')
```

Comment: Can i use combination like p = Post.objects.all().prefetch_related('tag').extra(select={'count':"select count(*) from blog_tag,blog_post where blog_post.id=blog_tag.post_id group by blog_post.id"} for additional comments count field

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you want to use a [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) in your Tag model.  In Django, a ForeignKey is a many-to-one, while you'd probably prefer a [many-to-many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#ref-manytomany) relationship (meaning: one post can have multiple tags and one tag can refer to multiple posts).

To deal with performance issues, I'm using [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related):

> Returns a QuerySet that will “follow” foreign-key relationships,
>   selecting additional related-object data when it executes its query.
>   This is a performance booster which results in a single more complex
>   query but means later use of foreign-key relationships won’t require
>   database queries.

Comment: Thx, i think about this , but i saw this example in documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name . But now i shure, that many-to-many is the best approach

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [django-taggit](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit)? It may make your life easier. Just plug it in and go. The documentation has some example queries for what you may want to do.

Comment: Thx, I know about this app, but it is for the understanding of Django and in some test tasks need to use own tags.